# nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name 'GroupMessageInfo'

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

error message:

[image]

```
persistentStoreCoordinator is nil ??
persistentStoreCoordinator is nil ??
persistentStoreCoordinator is nil ??
persistentStoreCoordinator is nil ??
persistentStoreCoordinator is nil ??
persistentStoreCoordinator is nil ??
persistentStoreCoordinator is nil ??
persistentStoreCoordinator is nil ??
persistentStoreCoordinator is nil ??
------------ persistentStoreCoordinator is nil ??
```

---

```
- (void)updateGroupTableStatus:(TmpGroupMessageInfo*)info { 

NSManagedObjectContext *ctx = [self createPrivateObjectContext];

[ctx performBlock:^{
    NSPredicate *cdt = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"groupId == %@ && tableId == %@", info.groupId, info.tableId];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [GroupMessageInfo makeRequest:ctx predicate:cdt orderby:nil offset:0 limit:1];
    NSArray *array = [ctx executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
    if ([array count] > 0) {
        for (GroupMessageInfo *msg in array) {
            msg.lastingTime = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:0];
        }
        [ctx save:nil];
        [self.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
            [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
        }];
    }
}];
}
```

---

```
+ (NSFetchRequest*)makeRequest:(NSManagedObjectContext*)ctx predicate:(NSPredicate*)predicate orderby:(NSArray*)orders offset:(int)offset limit:(int)limit {
NSString *className = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:object_getClassName(self)];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:className inManagedObjectContext:ctx]];
if (predicate) {
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
}
if (orders!=nil) {
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:orders];
}
if (offset>0) {
    [fetchRequest setFetchOffset:offset];
}
if (limit>0) {
    [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:limit];
}
return fetchRequest;}
```

---

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext*)createPrivateObjectContext {
if (_privateManagedObjectContext == nil) {
    _privateManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    [_privateManagedObjectContext setParentContext:self.managedObjectContext];
}

return _privateManagedObjectContext;
  }
```

---

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        return _managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (coordinator != nil) {
        _managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
        [_managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];
    }
    return _managedObjectContext;
}

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"PokerSkyModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
    _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return _managedObjectModel;
}

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {
    if (_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
        return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }

    ......

    _persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:optionsDictionary error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        [self cleanData];
        abort();
    }
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

Comment: Has the stack been created before you're calling in from a background thread?

Answer (score 0):

I came a cross exactly the same crash with yours. Finally I found out that initialize `persistentStoreCoordinator` of `NSManagedObjectContext` **cannot** be placed in **background thread**!

In your case, you do some CoreData operation at No.11 thread which is obviously not the **Main Thread**.If it is the first time you access your `CoreData`, then the `persistentStoreCoordinator` will be set at your No.11 background thread which lead to the crash. You can also reproduce the crash by putting these code `appDidFinishLaunch` at `AppDelegate`

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {  
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ 
        // your CoreData operation here
    }
    // ...
}
```

The solution is quite easy, just ensure the initialization of CoreData(or the first time you use it) should be at **Main Thread**.When it's not, using GCD to switch to it

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), 0), ^{ 
    // your CoreData initialize here
}
```