# Init NSManagedObjectContext and NSPersistentStoreCoordinator on background thread

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to find an official answer due to a crash i experienced, which is similar to this:
[nil is not a legal NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for searching for entity name 'GroupMessageInfo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698235/nil-is-not-a-legal-nspersistentstorecoordinator-for-searching-for-entity-name-g)

I couldn't find an official answer/documentation to this:
Can I init NSManagedObjectContext and NSPersistentStoreCoordinator on background thread? or it must be on the main thread?

Would love to get some references.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType` as `NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.mainQueueConcurrencyType`, you should initialize that `NSManagedObjectContext` in **MainThread** only.

Otherwise You should use `NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.privateQueueConcurrencyType` to initialize `NSManagedObjectContext` in an another thread.

Please refer this [article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/using_core_data_in_the_background) for more info.